# What is the simplest way to clear all pseudo classes on an element?

Tags: css

I am writing a stylesheet to extend a base stylesheet whose CSS has many pseudo classes applied to certain elements.  I would like my stylesheet to override some of these styles with a single style that is applied to an element no matter what state it is in, whether hovered on, focussed etc.

For example, the base stylesheet might have the styles

```
.classname {
   color:#f00;
}

.classname:hover {
   color:#0f0;
}

.classname:active {
   color:#00f;
}
```

but adding the following after these styles does not override the pseudo states...

```
.classname {
   color:#fff;
}
```

The following works, but it feels a lot of code for something that seems simple.

```
 .classname,
 .classname:active,
 .classname:hover,
 .classname:focus,
 .classname:visited,
 .classname:valid{
    color:#fff;
  }
```

Likewise, I know an `!important` would work, but that's normally a warning sign of a poorly structured stylesheet.

Is there anything along the lines of a `.classname:*` that would cover every possible state, or some way to simply remove all pseudo classes?

Comment: If there would, it would be `:* {}`. But there is none.

Comment: Have you tried `tagname.classname`, since you don't wan't to use `!important` and `.classname` itself didn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are able to put the classes inside some wrapper `id` you can prevent the pseudo-classes to take effect due to specificity:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.classname {
   color:#f00;
}
.classname:hover {
   color:#0f0;
}
.classname:active {
   color:#00f;
}
#a .classname {
   color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="classname">all pseudo works</div>

<div id="a">
  <div class="classname">none of the pseudo works</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think, it could be solved with `:any` pseudo-class.

```
<a href="google.com">Google</a>

<style>
a:link { color: blue; }
a:hover { color: red; }
a:-webkit-any(a) { color: green; }
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ycfokuju

Browser support is not perfect: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:any

**Edit:**

Actually, as I discovered, this answer isn't very accurate. (Despite it was upvoted 4 times, lol).

- First of all, you don't need `:any` fot this task. You need `:any-link`.
- The second point is that `:any` itself is a former name of `:matches`. So, in our terminology we should use terms `:any-link` and `:matches` and don't use term `:any`.

Example of using `:any-link`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any-link

Examples of using `:mathes`: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/

I haven't edited the code itself, so fix it yourself according to this new information.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like it could be the best answer when there is more browser support, but Dekel's solution seems the most robust for now.

Comment: Yes, I also think Dekel's answer is more stable and, for this reason, better then mine :-)

Comment: This information is severely out of date. The note about `:any-link` is very useful, but the answer should be corrected with the outdated information removed.